# How to give color first five Li or last five Li in ten list of a UL?

Tags: html, css

How can I give color to first or last five Li in a ten list of UL?

```css
.list-inline{margin:0; padding:0;}
.list-inline > li{list-style:none; display:inline-block; float:left; background:#000; color:#fff; padding:6px 12px; text-align:center;}
.list-inline > li.class-name?{}
```

```html
<ul class="list-inline">
 <li>Example</li>
 <li>Example</li>
 <li>Example</li>
 <li>Example</li>
 <li>Example</li>
 <li>Example</li>
 <li>Example</li>
 <li>Example</li>
 <li>Example</li>
 <li>Example</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

**First five:** using `:nth-child(-n+5)`

```css
.list-inline {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.list-inline>li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.list-inline>li:nth-child(-n+5) {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example</li>
</ul>
```

**Last five:** using `:nth-last-child(-n+5)`

```css
.list-inline {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.list-inline>li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.list-inline>li:nth-last-child(-n+5) {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example</li>
  <li>Example</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just add one class in li which you want color like: "red-color"

```css
.list-inline{margin:0; padding:0;}
.list-inline > li{list-style:none; display:inline-block; float:left; background:#000; color:#fff; padding:6px 12px; text-align:center;}
.list-inline > li.red-color{color:red}
```

```html
<ul class="list-inline">
 <li class="red-color">Example</li>
 <li class="red-color">Example</li>
 <li class="red-color">Example</li>
 <li class="red-color">Example</li>
 <li class="red-color">Example</li>
 <li>Example</li>
 <li>Example</li>
 <li>Example</li>
 <li>Example</li>
 <li>Example</li>
</ul>
```